# Understand how to extract the dependencies from the package.json file for an angular application to scan the non-bundled/minified version

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

I need to scan all the libraries that we deploy with our angular application. However since the build process bundles all of the libraries together I am not able to scan the individual libraries. I can scan the raw node_modules directory however that has both devDependencies and dependencies. I really only want to scan the dependencies because that is what actually gets deployed.

I looked into setting up my own custom webpack config but it doesnt seem I can add my own "architect" section in the angular.json. I want to keep the existing build process intact and just have a secondary one that could use the custom webpack config. Unfortunately when I tried this it said that command does not exist for ng.

If anyone has any thoughts, ideas or other references for me that would be greatly appreciated. It does not have to be a change to the angular.json. Maybe there are some other possibilities that I could explore to pull in all of the libraries listed under the package.json dependencies section.

Answer (score 0):

To add custom build settings, you may create a new configuration on `angular.json` like bellow:

```
  "architect": {
    "build": {
      // ...
      "configurations": {
        "quality": {
          // ...
        },
        "production": {
          // ...
        }
      }
    },
```

In this example I've created a custom `quality` configuration as a copy of production and changed it to my needs. Also, I've created a custom `environment.qa.ts` file inside environments folder (and pointed `quality` config to it) to set the appropriate constants to be used on the build.

You may then run the build using your custom configuration with this command: `ng build --configuration quality`

To have insights on your bundle content and package sizes, you may use [webpack-bundle-analyzer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-bundle-analyzer) which provides a very nice view of your bundle.

Comment: Yeah i understand setting up different configurations but there did not appear to be any configuration settings that allowed me to have it not bundle the js files together. This was the first thing I checked so unless there is a setting that I was not aware of then I don't think that this would solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

So after digging around for other solutions I found that I can just do `npm prune --production` or start with `npm install --only=production` which does exactly what I need to isolate the dependencies from the devDependencies in the node_modules directory. There is no need for me to modify or change how the build process happens for my application in angular-cli. I can grab all the *.js files from the node_modules directory after the prune command runs and then trigger my security scan against the files.